# firefox font doesn't work

Tags: html, css, fonts

I've found strange problem on my site.
If add font in style like

```
font: 2.0625em/1em 'ColiseumCRoman';
```

it doesn't work in FF (28.0 version and in 29.0.1 the same problem)
Does not work neither the size nor the line-height nor the font. Caption is displayed by the default font.

but if I change style like

```
font-size: 2.0625em;
line-height: 1em;
font-family: 'ColiseumCRoman';
```

it works absolutely correct in FF!
I don't understand why! What's going on ?

PS. I use `@font-face` for adding this font

```
@font-face { /*ColiseumC*/
    font-family: 'ColiseumCRoman';
    src: url('../fonts/coliseumc.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/coliseumc.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/coliseumc.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/coliseumc.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/coliseumc.svg#ColiseumCRoman') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: This is indeed odd. Well, for me the syntax works in FF29 with web-safe fonts. It's also standard CSS. Are you sure, your actual code hasn't got white-space where none should be, or too little of it? (spaces around the `/`, no space before font family, ...)

Comment: `2.0625em` seems weirdly precise :D

Comment: Also, do the DevTools show anything? Is the rule even there in them? If not, the parsing already failed.

Comment: Yes, I'm absolutely sure! The fonts work perfectly in Opera and Google Chrome, but in FF I have this problem.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol not necessarily. The `625` part means usually, that the resulting pixel value will be a round number.

Comment: 2.0625em * 16px = 33px

Comment: Aah, I see. Makes sense. It's just more decimals than I'm used to. At the risk of sounding ignorant, is there a reason to use `2.0625em` over `33px`?

Comment: which OS are you using? I had similar problem, I solved by converting my font using online font converter

Comment: I've found, it works if I use `px`, not `em` like `font: 58px/46px 'ColiseumCRoman';` But I still do not understand what the problem is.

Comment: I've already converted my font using online font converter.

Comment: I have found what was wrong! In some styles I added `bold` - like `font: 2.0625em/1em bold 'ColiseumCRoman';` so, it didn't work. I remove `bold` and now all works correct.

Comment: You can have the `bold`, too. Just stick it to the front: `font: bold 2em/1 'Colliseum';`

Comment: If you don't mind, I'm voting for closing it now.

Comment: I don't mind, it's not actual now )